# R: faste determine k nearest neigher for each row, other element set to zero and normalize it

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to determine k nearest neighbor for `each row` a matrix, here is my code, I think data.table can do it more efficient, but currently, I can not figure it out

```
mm <- matrix(c(5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4), 3, 2)
mm <- tcrossprod(mm)
getNearest <- function(simmat, k = 2) {
    res <- apply(simmat, 1, function(x) {
        s <- sort(x, index.return = TRUE)
        x[s$ix[1:(length(x) - k)]] <- 0
        return(x)
      }  
    )
   return(res / rowSums(res))
}
getNearest(mm, k = 2)

> getNearest(mm, k = 2)
      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.6071429 0.0000000 0.3928571
[2,] 0.0000000 0.5416667 0.4583333
[3,] 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.0000000
```

The original mm is:

```
> mm
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   34   20   22
[2,]   20   26   22
[3,]   22   22   20
```

For 2000 by 2000 matrix and k = 30, it will cost 1.17 seconds, is there more efficient way to finish the same thing, in `data.table`?

Thanks.

Comment: There are packages and functions for k nearest neighbor you might consider. You might also want to show your best guess at a data.table solution.